# Catch acceleration event on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, acceleration

I have a menu that like a roulette, it's spinning like a whell.
To catch the events i'm using `touch began/move`.

How can i add it an `acceleration` ? I want to register to an `acceleration`  event, when user touch an item and slide??

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html)

```
Listing 4-4  Receiving an accelerometer event
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
UIAccelerationValue x, y, z;
x = acceleration.x;
y = acceleration.y;
z = acceleration.z;

// Do something with the values.
}
```

Comment: How can i know from this code a numerical size of the acceleration? so check whether it's bigger\smaller from value?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006901

Comment: Maybe i wrote it wrong...i need the angular acceleration of the spinning wheel, the "power" of spinning,Is this code event can help me?